# Why doesn't JSON open?

Tags: python-3.x

`

```
import requests

link = "https://developers.lingvolive.com/"

paramsGet = {'text': 'cat', 'srcLang': '1033', 'dstLang': '1049'}
headerGet = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SmxlSEFpT2pFMk56RXdNek14TURRc0lrMXZaR1ZzSWpwN0lrTm9ZWEpoWTNSbGNuTlFaWEpFWVhraU9qVXdNREF3TENKVmMyVnlTV1FpT2pjek1ERXNJbFZ1YVhGMVpVbGtJam9pT0RkaU1UazJNekF0TldNMFppMDBNREZqTFRrMk1EQXRObVk1Wm1JeFlqVXpObVkzSW4xOS5aekJvM3oyWmUycGRJVkRMbjE0ZFJIdlVaWEQybFhJLW9RTmFPanJneV9V'}

responseGet = requests.get(link, params=paramsGet, headers=headerGet)

print(responseGet.json())
```

`

Never done this before, how to implement?

Comment: you **really** shouldn't just put your API token on the internet for everyone to see... at this point, you should invalidate that token and create a new one. in any case, please describe the actual problem you are experiencing

Comment: Response is not json, it's HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you're not making any attempt to access the API; you're just loading the main web page. It looks like there is [api documentation available](https://developers.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/Help) which you should probably read.

For what you're trying to do it seems like you want the [Translation API endpoint](https://developers.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/Help/Api/GET-api-v1-Translation_text_srcLang_dstLang_isCaseSensitive). That might look like this:

```
import pprint
import requests

link = "https://developers.lingvolive.com/"

paramsGet = {'text': 'cat', 'srcLang': '1033', 'dstLang': '1049'}
headerGet = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'}

res = requests.get(f'{link}/api/v1/Translation', params=paramsGet, headers=headerGet)
res.raise_for_status()
print(res.text)
```

Which produces about 40KB of JSON output so I'm not going to include it here, but it starts like this:

```
[
  {
    "Title": "cat",
    "TitleMarkup": [
      {
        "IsItalics": false,
        "IsAccent": false,
        "Node": "Text",
        "Text": "cat",
        "IsOptional": false
      }
    ],
    "Dictionary": "LingvoUniversal (En-Ru)",
    "ArticleId": "LingvoUniversal (En-Ru)__cat",
    "Body": [
```